# UITableview inside cell, second UItableview only 1 row, should be more than 1 row

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uitableviewsectionheader, uitableviewrowaction

[image]

So I'm trying making a multi-level `UITableView` by using UITableView inside `UITableViewCell`. Let me explain first:

1. **Red color** is Main `UITableView`
2. **Blue color** is Section, so I use as SectionHeader, and add UIButton into it, so can be expanded, and
3. **Green Color**, is the `cellForRow` that include UITableView inside cell.
4. The flow is, I get all Blue color items which is each Blue Color have children Green
5. In this logic, if I want to show all blue color as section, so in `numberOfSection` I `return [blueData count];`
6. And `numberOfRowsInSection`, of course I get from `GreenModel *greenData = [blueData.greenData count];`
7. In cellForRow, I'm using `UITableView` inside cell, so I define `blueDatarArray` and pass it into cell with properties, like this:  `cell.greenDataArray = [blueDataArray.greenData mutableCopy];`
8. In `UITableViewCell` I have `UITableView`, which is there will be `UITableView Delegate` and `UITableView DataSource`
9. Continue from number 8, I also use a header as return greenData array, which is, from blue having a child is green, and I set in number of section in `UITableViewCell`'s delegate and data source is, `numberOfSections` in green tableview is refer from number 7 as `[greenDataArray count];` so it will be used for header, and also I give button too into it, used to expand and collapse later.
10. Also in cellForRow, it return `[greenData.child count]`
11. And finally in cellForRow is only show up greenData's child but does not appear, take a look at the picture the green having 4 children, but when. I trigger the button, it wont show up... why? I use same logic as red and blue.

How to show greenData's child?